# Is there a way to run powershell scripts with elevated privileges as part of a yaml pipeline?

Tags: powershell, azure-pipelines-yaml, chocolatey

I'm struggling with creating an azure yaml pipeline to download and install a chocolatey package. I figured the best way to do that was via a Powershell@2 task but I'm open to ideas, but I'm running into access issues. Below is the task:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Install Chocolatey Package'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    errorActionPreference: 'stop'
    failOnStderr: true
    script: |
      choco install -y MyPackage --version 1.0.0 -s MySource
```

This is run on a self-hosted agent that is spun up as part of a scaleset, so the machine isn't known in advance. When this runs, it appears to download the package fine, but then is unable to do anything with it and the logs show lots of errors trying to access the package itself as well as warnings that it's not running with elevated privileges. Assuming that running this task with elevated privileges would fix this, how can that be done?

Comment: What you are experiencing, is by design. PS always runs in the user context of the user who launched it. [PS script elevation is a common thing - lot's on the web about it](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell+script+auto+elevate%27&t=h_&ia=web), though not YAML related), but it has limitations depending on the permissions to the user launching the script. Otherwise, you need to set a scheduled task with the proper creds to run what you need. You cannot run interactive tools without an interactive user. Installs require access to a user profile, which is not loaded until a user logs on.

Comment: check that the identity that is running the agent is a local admin on the machine. This should allow you to do this